# How to link Heroku app to private Github Repo?

Tags: git, github, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and I'm not familiar with the Deploy/Pipeline verbiage.

I already have the Heroku CLI installed and I deployed an app using:

```
run: heroku create myNewHerokuApp
```

My instance is now made.

I have a private repo on Github.

```
https://github.com/myUserName/myPrivateRepoName.git
```

How do I link my `myNewHerokuApp` with `myPrivateRepoName.git`?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration).

> You can configure GitHub integration in the Deploy tab of apps in the
>   [Heroku Dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/). To configure GitHub integration, you have to
>   authenticate with GitHub. You only have to do this once per Heroku
>   account.

After that you can find public or private repo in this panel:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link from heroku's documentation that tells you exactly how to do this , follow these steps and you will connect your repo with your heroku app

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration

Comment: I could not find any steps regarding deploying private GitHub repo!