# Problem to access the private library that I need, using heroku deploy

Tags: flutter, heroku, ssh

Currently I'm trying to deploy a flutter web project on heroku that using a private library on azure devops. I access this private library using SSH key from my PC. The problem is when I try to access the library from dyno, that is not have any ssh key previously registered.

What I want to know is: How can I access my private library from the project that I'm deploying?

```
Running "flutter pub get" in build_7d8ec7f9...                  
Git error. Command: `git clone --mirror ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/example/project/sdk /app/.pub-cache/git/cache/sdk-b3499e8736208204591e9ce10402ffa3d77b19aa`
stdout: 
stderr: Cloning into bare repository '/app/.pub-cache/git/cache/sdk-b3499e8736208204591e9ce10402ffa3d77b19aa'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128
       pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link Heroku app to private Github Repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417963/how-to-link-heroku-app-to-private-github-repo)

Comment: @doesnotmatter, I don't think so. OP has a private _dependency_. That question is about a private _project_.

Comment: That's it @Chris. My project has a private dependecy that need a SSH key to access, I really don't know how to do that on heroku

Comment: Not sure. On GitLab I'd point you to deploy tokens, but Azure DevOps doesn't seem to support them. You could try publishing a package on Azure Artifacts, but it doesn't look like it supports Dart (presumably that's what you're using based on `flutter pub get`?) There's [Gemfury](https://gemfury.com/), but it similarly doesn't seem to support Dart.

Comment: Seems like I'm behind the eight ball, but I will try look forward on azure artifacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved giving up on the SSH. Now I'm using the generated personal tokens and using in pubpec like that:

```
ur_private_library:
    git:
      url: https://<token-name>:<token-password>@dev.azure.com/<your-repo-url>
```

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) to learn how to create personal token acess